# PLC Siemens S7-1200 and TIA Portal - Change IP address

Tags: ip-address, plc, siemens, tia-portal

I'm having a strange problem with TIA Portal and S7-1200 Siemens PLC.

I need to change the IP address of PLC, but I have not TIA Portal project of the machine. I tried using *Online access* > *Diagnostic* > *Functions* > *Assign IP Address* but TIA Portal says "the IP address could not be assigned".

The IP has to be changed from 192.168.50.xyz to 192.168.40.xyz

Tia version is v17 both on PLC and pc.

What I checked:

- I can ping the PLC;
- I can view program blocks in PLC;
- I can start / stop the PLC.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use all the tools to initially set the IP address.  But once set, things change; the function of the various tools becomes dependent on the value of this setting in the program running on the PLC:

[image: PLC IP address settings]

**Using *Online access > Diagnostic > Functions > Assign IP Address*** or **Proneta**

Based on my experience.

If "Set IP address in the project" was selected, you can't change the IP address.

If "IP address is set directly at the device" is selected, I don't know what happens.

**Using SIMATIC Automation Tool**

(you can obtain a trial version here: [Simatic Automation Tool](https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/document/98161300/))

According to the documentation (section 3.1): if "Set IP address in the project" was selected, you can assign a temporary address until the CPU is next power cycled.  If "IP address is set directly at the device," you can permanently change the IP address.

**By upload and download**

If none of the above options will work, you can upload the PLC project using *Online\Upload Station as a New Device (Hardware and Software)*, modify the IP address and download *just* the hardware configuration.  I won't get into the details of this, but beware of networked IO and TIA portal versions.

Comment: Well that's exaclty the explanation I was looking for. I noticed I can change IP address (various method are available) but I was wondering why the original IP is restored after a power cycle. I'll try with download just hardware configuration. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First, I find it much better to use this free software tool developed by siemens to change the ip address.  It is much easier.  It is called proneta.  You can google search it or go to the link below.

[Proneta download link](https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/document/67460624/proneta-basic-3-3-commissioning-and-diagnostics-tool-for-profinet?dti=0&lc=en-WW)

Second, is any other profinet cable connected to the plc?  If so disconnect the cable going in to the plc (and possibly remove the re-apply the power) and try again.  There are many times where another device can write an ip address to the device.

Comment: Tried with Proneta, too. There are no devices changing PLC IP address - the problem is it is set in the project. Thank you anyway!